# How to encode long-string in the DB where attribute type is varchar(254)?

Tags: java, database

Say for some reason I’ve got a table in the DB that only have varchar(254) attribute types.
So in other words, I cannot store a String directly which has more than 254 characters.

But would there be a way around this, i.e. is it possible to encode a long string (say  approx 700 chars) in the DB given this constraint.

What would be the easiest way to do this? I use Java.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the nature of the string you're wanting to store, you *might* be able to compress it down to the required length.

However, this is a can of worms. If I were in your shoes, I'd first investigate whether widening the column is an option (in most SQL DBMSs all it takes is a simple `ALTER COLUMN` command).

P.S. If you **have** to compress the data, take a look at the [`Deflater`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) class. However, if I were you, I'd fight really hard for that trivial schema change.

Comment: @aix But given my requirements, I am not permitted to alter the schema in any way (for instance, I could easily change to byte[] and serialise) but I am not allowed to do this. So given I can only work in String, what are they ways for compressing string data?

Comment: @aix thanks for the update. that’s true, I should work on changing the schema, but just to consider the alternative: the Deflater still requires a byte[], could I deflate a long-string into a shorter string?

Comment: I would agree with aix here, the change you are suggesting is at the database level, anything that you would do at java level may fail at some corner cases in future and come back and bite you in the ... Ask the DBA to make the change otherwise the logic will fail.

Comment: @aix Could you please give a small example. The API has Deflater.delate only apply to a byte[] output? How could I specify a String output?